# How to fix: MongoParseError: Invalid connection string while trying to connect between docker containers

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to connect two docker containers. The first one is mongo and the other one is nodejs.

I have tried using bridge network. Actually, if I ping mongo from the nodejs container, it works. Unfortunately, I can't connect to my mongo using the `MONGO_URI=mongo://mongo:27017/DB_NAME.`

nodejs - .dockercompose

```
version: '3'

services:
  nodejs:
    build:
      context: ./nodejs
    ports:
      - ${DOCKER_PORT}:3000
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
    network_mode: bridge
```

mongo - .dockercompose

```
version: '3'

services:
  mongo:
    image: mongo:xenial
    restart: always
    entrypoint: "mongod --bind_ip_all"
    expose:
      - 27017
    ports:
      - ${MONGO_PORT}:27017
    volumes:
      - /data/db/mongo:/data/db
    network_mode: bridge
```

The error that was showing:

```
MongoParseError: Invalid connection string
    at parseConnectionString (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/uri_parser.js:505:21)
    at connect (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/mongo_client_ops.js:195:3)
    at connectOp (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/mongo_client_ops.js:284:3)
    at executeOperation (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:416:24)
    at MongoClient.connect (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:175:10)
    at /usr/src/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:612:12
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:609:19)
    at Mongoose.connect (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:321:15)
    at connect (/usr/src/app/src/db/index.js:9:20)
    at tryCatch (/usr/src/app/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:45:40)
    at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (/usr/src/app/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:271:22)
    at Generator.prototype.<computed> [as next] (/usr/src/app/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:97:21)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:3:24)
    at _next (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:25:9)
    at /usr/src/app/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:32:7 {
  name: 'MongoParseError',
  [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {}
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can not connect from two different docker-compose using the container name. So better to keep them in a single config file. but still you can access using Host IP in the nodejs app.

```
version: '3.1'
services:
  mongo:
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: test
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: example 
    networks:
      - mongonetwork
  web:
    image: "node:alpine"
    depends_on:
      - mongo
    networks:
      - mongonetwork
networks:
  mongonetwork:
    driver: bridge
```

Set username, pass and database in your mongo environment variable.

And also the connection string is not valid.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://mongo/test', {useNewUrlParser: true});
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose